# Remove & Add Rows using Joins in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to update 2 tables that happen to be linked in a 1 to many connection.

I am using R to connect to the database for preprocessing before running the appropriate SQL functions. my question is are the SQL functions I plan to use a good method or is there a better way to accommodate this type of data.

Example

```
DataFrame in R

ID      GroupID   Group_Name       Scores
1       1         "Ride High"      "100,90,85"
2       2         "Flaming Idiots" "90,50,78"
```

R code to generate tables (I'm using Tidyverse)

```
GroupDF <- tibble(GroupID = DataFrame$GroupID,Group_Name=DataFrame$Group_Name)
ScoreDF <- tibble(GroupID = DataFrame$GroupID,Scores=DataFrame$Scores)
ScoreDF <- separate_rows(ScoreDF,Scores,sep = ',',convert = TRUE)

dbWriteTable(Con,'Group_Update',GroupDF)
dbWriteTable(Con,'Score_Update',ScoreDF)
```

SQL code (Does this make sense)

```
UPDATE Group_Table Gr 
       INNER JOIN Group_Update UG on Gr.GroupID = UG.GroupID
              set Gr.Group_Name = UW.Group_Name;

DELETE Sc FROM Score_Table Sc
    RIGHT JOIN Score_Update SU ON sc.GroupID = SU.GroupID;

INSERT INTO Score (GroupID,Scores)
SELECT 
   GroupID, Scores
FROM 
   Score_Update;
```

How I rationalised the problem is, The 1-to-1 connection can be a straight forward update using joins but the 1-to-many column had to first have the existing data removed from the database before the new data could be added.

End Result

```
Group Table
ID      GroupID   Group_Name                 ID      GroupID   Group_Name
1       1         "Low Rider"                1       1         "Ride High"
2       2         "Hot Flames"       ->      2       2         "Flaming Idiots"
3       3         "Happy Roads"              3       3         "Happy Roads"
4       4         "Runners"                  4       4         "Runners"

Score Table
ID    GroupID    Scores                      ID    GroupID    Scores
#     1          100                         #     1          100
#     1          90                          #     1          90
#     2          0                           #     1          85
#     3          70                          #     2          90
#     3          70                          #     2          50
#     3          70                          #     2          78
...                                          #     3          70
                                             #     3          70
                                             #     3          70
                                             ...
```

Is this efficient or logical?

Comment: Group is a reserved word in mysql you will need to enclose every occurance with backticks.Or change the name,